# General DNS issue

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I've registered domain: `denisit.net`

In the registrar's setting I pointed that name servers are

```
ns0.xname.org ns1.xname.org
```

At xname.org, I created A record for the domen:

```
denisit.net. IN A 195.225.158.230
```

After 24h I can't resolve any of my domains.

It seems like servers have not renewed records. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dig denisit.net reveals a SERVFAIL. Although a whois lookup reveals, xname's nameservers, it looks like none of the records are served.

Can you try an alternate DNS hosting service like [pointhq](https://pointhq.com/) or [zerigo](http://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns) ? Both of them have free plans.

Comment: I'll try to and public results. Thx.

Comment: I've tried https://pointhq.com everything works perfect. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no answer for NS for this zone :

```
$ host -t NS denisit.net
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

So your registrar didn't active your zone in his DNS. In addition, xname servers didn't know denisit.net.

```
$ host -t NS denisit.net. ns0.xname.org
Using domain server:
Name: ns0.xname.org
Address: 195.234.42.1#53
Aliases: 

denisit.net has no NS record
```

So double check your configuration, there is a problem on both sides !

Comment: It seems like I missunderstand something: 

$ dig denisit.net +trace


denisit.net.            172800  IN      NS      ns0.xname.org.

denisit.net.            172800  IN      NS      ns1.xname.org.


it looks like NS answer is correct?

Comment: This might also help you to understand: http://www.intodns.com/denisit.net

Answer (score 2):

**XName DNS-hosting died, unfortunately**

Even when their NSes online, servers don't reload zones on change,e-mails did produce any reaction.

When I was thinking about moving I selected between DNSHat & DNSexit, **use** now **DNSexit** (4 NSes, zones reloaded **in minutes** after change, SOA not editable, format of serial doesn't follow *standard de-facto*). DNSHat leave still not tried